# CSS anmation off hover

Tags: css

I have this CSS code and zooms in on an image on hover, what I am trying to do now, is when the item is off hover for image to animate back to its original position

```
.item: hover img {
-webkit-animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-out 1;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-out 1;
        animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-out 1;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}
```

How would I accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use transitions instead of animations. It'd go something like this.

```
.item {
  color: orange;
  transition:
    color 1s,
    transform 1s;
}

.item:hover {
  color: darkorange;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

[More info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify all of this and just use ease-in-out and scale =)

```
.item img {
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```